# Can the VBScript data transfer from array to row be faster?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a situation where my Dictionary object `Keys` are nothing but the row numbers and the `Items` are Each row details(i.e. Item is an 1D array).

Now with the help of the below code I can push back the row details to from Dictionary Items(arrays) to the rows. But can we do it in one line instead one - by -one?

```
Sub DataPushBackToSheet(DicTotDurations,DicHoldData,ob9)

    Dim Key,ColumntoStart,LastColNumber

    ColumntoStart = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Parent Business Process ID", ob9.Rows(1), 0) + 1
    LastColNumber = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ob9.Rows(1))

    For Each Key in DicHoldData.Keys

         ob9.Range(ob9.Cells(Key,ColumntoStart),ob9.Cells(Key,ColumntoStart)).Resize(1, UBound(DicHoldData.Item(Key)) + 1).Value = DicHoldData.Item(Key)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be VBA. Why mention VbScript ?

Comment: @iDevlop I developed the code in .vbs file, .vbs is much similer to vba!

Comment: Why don't you use an Array where the index is the rownumber instead of an Dictionary? A dictionary is quite fast, but an array will be faster.

Comment: Good point by AutomatedChaos. You could create a 1D array direct from your Excekl range using `objExcel1.Transpose(your single column range)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) or [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) you can dump the items or keys directly

**VBS**

```
Dim objExcel
Dim objWB
Dim objDic
Dim objKeys
Set objExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
objDic.Add "apple", 1
objDic.Add "pear", 2
objDic.Add "turkey", 3
objKeys = objDic.keys
objWB.Sheets(1).Range("a1").Resize(UBound(objKeys) + 1) = objExcel.Transpose(objKeys)
```

**VBA**

```
Sub DummyKeys()
Dim objDic
Dim objKeys
Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
objDic.Add "apple", 1
objDic.Add "pear", 2
objDic.Add "turkey", 3
objKeys = objDic.keys
Range("a1").Resize(UBound(objKeys) + 1) = Application.Transpose(objKeys)
End Sub
```

Comment: I have no way to hold the row number as Dictionary key, and all the row details as array of Item. I put the row details to the Item, as I need to do much operations on them.

Comment: If i haven't answered your questions then you can you pls be clearer as to what you have, and what you would like to do.

Comment: here my dictionary Items are not a single Item,rather one key is holding array of Items. these Item is nothing but a full row.During the Item load with a key I used that row number as a key in my another `Sub` so that when I will push those Items back to the row,I can identify from which rows I picked those Item up. Please let me know if you need any more clarifications!

Comment: @VBSolver Then `loop through the dictionary` and `dump each item as an array` to the `range` using `Transpose`.. this is basics to you now, coz we have beent through it earlier ... :$

Comment: @bonCodigo I do know that,But I was thinking if that looping can also be done by any one liner. What you suggested in my above code i did the same,if you looked into the same.